# What are the subfields of cryptovirology?

Tags: cryptography, virus

What are the subfields of cryptovirology ? On wikipedia I can only find one subfield : Kleptography

Are there other subfields and are they already all defined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just looking for an enumerated list of topics?  Ransomware tops the list today.  But there are other malicious attacks that involve cryptography, including evading cryptography (such as protocol-downgrade attacks), exploiting asymmetric cryptography, deliberately introduced information-leaking side channels (aka kleptography), and the use of poor or questionable encryption (especially when a more trustworthy alternative may exist.)

If you haven't already, read [Malicious Cryptography: Exposing Cryptovirology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0764549758) by Young and Yung.  It was the first thesis specifically exploring the topic of cryptography-based malware.  The authors maintain a site at http://www.cryptovirology.com, which is more up to date.  It has a lot more information that is probably better suited to answer your specific questions.

Comment: Yes I'm looking for enumerated list of all subfields of "cryptovirology" in a centralized place instead of looking here and there - A clear list and not an evasive answers. I don't need explanation for each of them, I will do the search on my own, the links provided point in the right direction but I've already checked them like 3 years and also checked them before posting this, I need something clear - but thanks for your answers anyway.

Comment: @GERMANMASTER, calling cryptovirology a "field" may be too noble of a label.  It's simply the subset of any malware that involves cryptography in some way.  Young and Yung coined the term, so their site is the "definitive" source, in so much as anyone would have a claim to define sub-classifications of it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptovirology : "Cryptovirology is a field [...]",  "Kleptography, a subfield of cryptovirology [...]", "The field [...]", https://www.darknet.org.uk : "[...] in the field of Cryptovirology." and a bunch of others internet resources qualify it as a field, anyway as least your answer and this comment have the merits to clarify everything